# Story with a spaceship, earth, window washers, and titans?

Tags: story-identification, books, spaceship

I've read a book once, a few years ago. It was an old book, I could tell by the page color and the text font on the cover, so by now it's at least ten years old, probably more. It was a bigger book, judging by the size, I'd say between 150 and 350 pages. I think the cover had a circle looking spaceship. I think I got it from a school library, or maybe one of those 'take a book leave a book' places. Can't remember if there was ever a sequel.

I remember that the main character was in some sort of space station, running from something. Then I think a little bit later he jumps into space (with a space suit on) and ends up on the side of a docking spaceship. He cleans a window, then continues on his way. I think the pilot of the spaceship is in the story more later.

I remember something about 'Titan', and I specifically remember they capitalized the T.

I think the story opens up with an evacuation from Earth or something? It's been a while since I read it. Think it ends with the pilot of the docking ship and the window washer on a new planet.

I'm pretty sure someone betrays someone in it.

Comment: Titan with a capital "T" could be in reference to the moon of Jupiter. Can you recall if Jupiter comes up in the story and whether the station is in orbit around Jupiter or Titan?

If it is the moon, the book might be listed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_in_fiction

Comment: @Omnificer, i honestly have no idea. I can't remember anything besides what I put int he question. that does sound like a viable option tho, ill look into the wiki page.

Comment: @Omnificer Titan is a moon of ***Saturn*** not Jupiter!!

Comment: This sounds a lot like the plot of Titan A.E., though that's a movie.

Comment: That sounds a lot like the plot of the Novelization of the movie Titan A. E.

Comment: @WinchellChung, thats the one, thanks guys.

Comment: @user14111 Wow, major mistake on my part. In that case I would have recommended the novelization of 2001: A Space Odyssey which is Saturn. (But Jupiter in the film and the sequel novelization). However Titan A.E. looks like the answer.